# How to all parts of text except the second part of parentheses?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text in this format:

> ( (IP-MAT (CONJ vnnd)
>
> (NP-NOM (D das) (N wort))
>
> (BED war)
>
> (PP (P bey)
>
> (NP-DAT (NPR Gott)))
>
> (. ,))

I want to remove all parts of text except the second part of inner parentheses. in this example my aim is like this:

```
vnnd das wort war bey Gott ,
```

I used this code:

```
serach for: (?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))*?\(([$\w,.+-]+)\s+[$\w,.*?-]+\)+|(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))+$
replace with: $1
```

But it just save the first part. and I need the second part. How I can change the code to reach to my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++

Find What: `.*?([^ ]+?)\)+`
Replacement: `$1`

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pZ9vI5/1)

The above regex looks for anything after space and then followed by `)` one or more time.

Answer (score 0):

why not just match the character which you want ?

```
\w+(?=\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZCgaW3cp7dg-oW0_)

**Result:**

```
vnnd
das
wort
war
bey
Gott
```

Comment: But I don't want to delete matches words.
I need to save them.

Comment: @SoheilaB I mean: find other characters and remove them is difficult for regex, why not just get the characters what you want to keep?

Comment: Because I have millions of this parentheses in my text. It's so difficult for me match them and then separate them manually. I need matches word but saved matches words.